# Keyboard shortcut in kate for emmet to expand abbreviation

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, plasma-5, kate

Emmet exists in kate for a while in menu *Tools →  Scripts → Emmet* and there is sub-command "Expand abbreviation".

It works if I enter the abbreviation "lorem5" and then go deep for menu entry *Tools →  Scripts → Emmet → Expand abbreviation*.

But that's a long way and I want to make something similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (this combination is already taken for Go to Previous editing line).

What is default keyboard shortcut for emmet in kate or how to define new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open *Settings > Configure Kate > Configure Shortcuts*.
- In the window that opens, type <kbd>abbr</kbd> in the search box at the top.
- You should see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> as the default shortcut.
- Of course, you can change that to something else.

[image: Shortcut for expanding abbreviations in Kate]

Comment: At close view you will see we have two entries. Only setting at first one works (.. abbreviation not .. Abbreviation) in 19.10 and none of them in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @TadejP thanks for looking into this! I've seen "double" entires in Dolphin as well: There's an open bug at least a few months old: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409526.  So double entries seem to be a common problem with some KDE applications.